# How do I handle a mouse event within an element, but not on one of its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to handle a `mousedown` event one way on a parent element, but handle it differently if the event occurs on a child of that parent.

This:

```
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(){
  //stuff
});
```

will fire if any element within `.parent` is clicked, but I want to trigger the function only if the parent element is the only element being clicked, not one of it's children. **How can I do this?**

Comment: You can either check the target element being clicked, and only run the code if the target is the parent, or add mousedown handlers to the children and stop the propagation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind a handler to the child element, and use `event.stopPropagation()` in the child handler. Then the event won't bubble out to the parent.

Comment: Isn't creating an event handler just to stop propagation superfluous, especially when there's already a parent event handler?

Comment: He says he wants to handie it "differently" in the child. That different handling should be in the child's event handler. `stopPropagation` then serves to stop it from _also_ being handled in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the same as jQuery's `this` reference:

```
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(e){
  var child = $('.child-selector');
  if(e.target === this)
      // Run parent code
  if(e.target === child[0])
      // Run child code
});
```

**This is the suggestion found in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to mitigate event bubbling issues.**. This also does not require adding a handler with `stopPropagation()` to every child element, which is especially tedious if there are many child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an IF check inside your event to verify the location of the event. Something like:

```
$('.parent').on('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( e.target !== this ) 
       return;
    //...do your stuff stuff.. 
});
```

essentially saying if the e.target is not the same as the target then you have clicked something beside the parent...